# changing the value of a watchpoint in ring 0 gives rise to strange behavior of gdb

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

src.c:

```
main()
{
   char c='x';
   read(0,&c,1);
   printf("go\n");
   printf("come\n");
}
```

gcc src.c -g, you get a executable a.out,then,
gdb a.out

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483e5: file gdb.c, line 3.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/tx

Breakpoint 1, main () at gdb.c:3
3       char c='x';
(gdb) set $foo=&c
(gdb) watch *$foo   //set a watchpoint for the address in which c reside
Hardware watchpoint 2: *$foo
(gdb) del 1
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 2: *$foo

Old value = 0 '\0'
New value = 120 'x'
main () at gdb.c:4
4       read(0,&c,1);
(gdb) c
Continuing.       **//type carrige return**

Hardware watchpoint 2: *$foo

Old value = 120 'x'
New value = 10 '\n'
0x00ae3402 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb)
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap. **//from now on,gdb receive SIGTRAP repeatedly,why?**

0x009f23f3 in __read_nocancel () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb)
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x009f23f4 in __read_nocancel () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb)
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x009f23f9 in __read_nocancel () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

however,if i modify the source code to:

```
main()
{
    char c='x';

    printf("go\n");
    c++;

    printf("come\n");
}
```

then everything goes well,no wired behavior.

In the 1st program,the value of the watchpoint is modified in kernel mode,then gdb receive SIGTRAP;In the 2nd program,watchpoint is modified in user mode,nothing wired happen.could anyone tell me why? Heaps of thanks in advance.